# is there an alternative to change NetworkManager.conf

Tags: networking

I would need to programmatically change NetworkManager.conf, which is not straightforward to me(if someone knows a straightfoward way, please let me know). Is there an alternative way to configure the network device by "ADDING" a file. For example, if I would need to do unmanage a device, then adding a file that is much simpler than editing NetworkManager.conf. Thanks

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you are using? You can easily unmanage a device by e.g adding it to `/etc/network/interfaces`. There is also a ton of CLI options, like using nmcli, etc.

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20. I read somewhere that in Ubuntu 20 or later, interfaces is no longer used (I could be wrong). In NetworkManager.conf, I would need to add unmanaged-device=mac:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff. To do so, I would need to check whether it is there already, etc. If I can simply create a file, I do not need to worry the existing configuration file.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20, is it 20.04? If you add a device there NM will ignore the device.

Comment: about nmcli, someone said that it goes back to default after reboot.

Comment: yes, it is 20.04

Comment: It does go back after a reboot. You can run a command at start, or really add something to the NetworkManager.conf, it is not hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `nmcli`. If you want to unmanage a device, you can run

```
nmcli device set ifname <ifname> managed no
```

If you want permanently exclude a device from Network Manager, you can add a device to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: do I need to run after reboot? Thanks

Comment: You can add it to autostart. There are plenty of options. It is unclear what you are doing and why.

Comment: I have a USBLan device. I would need to configure it every time after reboot, and plug-in/remove.

Comment: A newbie question, in /etc/network/interfaces, I can configuration the device as I do in NetworkManager.conf? It works in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: No, format is different.